# Why does the activity not change on button click?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, android-activity, android-button

When trying you get the activity to change on the click of a button, I found you had to use Intent. But when used in my code it does not seem to work. Are there any problems with the code I have?

```
  public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private ListView recipes;
    Intent intent;
    Button button;
    EditText input;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.searchlist);

          //EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipeName);
          button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
          input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipeName);

          //recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recipes);
          //recipes.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.main, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BaconSandwich)));
          button.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      public void onClick(View clicked) {

          String value = input.getText().toString();
          Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          if(clicked == button) {
            recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recipes);
            Toast.makeText(this, "It is working for this item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RecipeMethodActivity.class);
            SearchActivity.this.startActivity(i);
          }
      }
```

Im not sure if it is just a simple naming error, or the way I am calling it is wrong. Any help would be great.

Also I have added the activity I want to change to (RecipeMethodActivity) into the Android Manifest.

Comment: Are you seeing both your Toast when you click the button?

Comment: What exactly means "does not work"? Read: What's in the LogCat? (In Eclipse: Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat)

Comment: No, I am only seeing the first toast actually, will try removing the if statement for now. Only issue is I eventually want the application to send data depending on what value was added to the text box.

Comment: For sending data with an Intent have a look at the various `putExtra()` methods. If you need further assistance open a new question for this once the Intent works :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double[]%29

Comment: Unfortunately by removing the if statement it still will not change activity, and also the toast message I am receiving does not match what has been set but rather a message that was removed.

Comment: The answer below would be the proper way to handle this. However, in your if(clicked == button) call, you would probably be better off using if( clicked.getID() == button.getID() )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the view's Id in your onClick method, like this:

```
public void onClick(View clicked) {

      String value = input.getText().toString();
      Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      if(clicked.getId() == R.id.submit) {
        recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recipes);
        Toast.makeText(this, "It is working for this item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RecipeMethodActivity.class);
        SearchActivity.this.startActivity(i);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have made the necessary changes, I first removed the intend and start activity and the toast ran fine producing the appropriate text. but when I changed and wanted to change the activity the application crashed. Any thoughts on what it might be from? Am I calling the start activity in the correct manor?

Comment: When it crashes just edit the question and post the error you'll find in LogCat.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand Log Cat at all, but from what I can gather the problem is the onCreate(RecipeMethodActivity). This activity does nothing and should be blank.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onClick` method, you are comparing whether or not the instance of two `View` objects are the same. Clearly, the `View` object passed to your `onClick` method is  not `==` to the private instance variable `Button button`.

You need to compare their IDs instead:

`if (view.getId() == R.id.button)`

Comment: David was faster but this answer provides the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried testing a view with `clicked == button`, but this should work in your onCreate():

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "It is working for this item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RecipeMethodActivity.class);
        SearchActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "It is working for this item.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), RecipeMethodActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("extra", extra);
        //use this ^ to transfer data from one activity to another
        startActivity(i);
        }});
```

Comment: With approach like this you don't have to implement `onClickListener`. Difference is that in this approach you instantiate new listener for every clickable element, but if you implement `onClickListener` you dont't need to instantiate for every clickable element.